# Prolog - Quotient and reminder. How it's work?

Tags: prolog

I have to give some examples quotient and reminder in Prolog but for now I don't understand how it's work.

- `quotient(X,Y,Q)` is true if X/Y = Q (in arithmetics natural numbers)
- `remainder(X,Y,R)` is true if X divided by Y give the rest R.

I would be grateful if someone could help me and explain me how it's work or gave me a link to the explanation.
Regards! ;)

Comment: `quotient(X,Y,Q):- Q is div(X,Y).` _and_  `remainder(X,Y,R):- R is mod(X,Y).`.

Comment: Thanks for help :)

Comment: Glad to help :) !!!